# Informatica Transaction Control Transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have to develop an informatica process that loads data from a flatfile into the target (simple truncate & load), but the catch is that :

**If the number of rejected rows is greater than 100, the process should stop, i.e. the session should fail & the data in the target must be rolled back to what it was originally before load.**

I think the TC Transformation might be useful here , but am not sure of how to use this. It would be great if I could get some help on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't use truncate in such scenario - it's irreversible. Try loading the data into a temporary table first (with `Truncate table` option enabled). Create a second session that will execute a set of sql commands like

```
`truncate table YourTable
 insert into YourTable select * from YourTempTable`
```

Link the two with a condition like `$yourTempTableSession.TgtFailedRows>100`.
To meet the second requirement (i.e. to fail the workflow) add a `Control task` and set it to `Abort top level workflow`. Add a link from the temp table session load with a condition like `$yourTempTableSession.TgtFailedRows>100`.